# Why is my script not iterating correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, puppeteer

The script works fine but I would like it to run more than once. I put what I thought was a completely normal basic for loop at the top surrounding the whole script with it.

Instead of running the script multiple times it just doubles every action of the script, eg. if I set the iterations variable to 2 it will just go through the script doing every action twice, whereas I want it to run the entire script from start to finish twice.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const C = require('./constants');
var USERNAME_SELECTOR;
var PASSWORD_SELECTOR;
var PHONE_SELECTOR;
var CTA_SELECTOR;
const URLL = process.argv[2];
var iterations = process.argv[3];
var usernameFieldWasFound = false;
var passwordFieldWasFound = false;
var buttonWasFound = false;
var phoneFieldWasFound = false;

for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {


async function startBrowser() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false})
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  return {browser, page};
}


async function closeBrowser(browser) {
  return browser.close();
}



(async () => {
  await playTest(URLL);
  process.exit(1);
})();


async function playTest(url) {
  const {browser, page} = await startBrowser();
  page.setViewport({width: 1366, height: 768});
  await page.goto(url);

  await delay(1500);



  // // creates a map of all links on the page
  // const allLinks = await page.$$eval('a', as => as.map(a => a.href));

  // // displays the number of links on the page
  // console.log(allLinks.length);

  // // contains the first link
  // // console.log(allLinks[0]);

  // console.log(allLinks);



  // searches for a username field, if statements are in order of likliehood of being the correct selector (least to most)

  if (await page.$('[type="text"]') !== null) {
    USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[type="text"]' 
  console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[type=text]"')
  usernameFieldWasFound = true; }  

  if (await page.$('#si_username') !== null) {
    USERNAME_SELECTOR = '#si_username';
    console.log ('Changed username field selector to #si_username')
    usernameFieldWasFound = true; }
 
  if (await page.$('[name="username"]') !== null) {
    USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[name="username"]' 
  console.log ('Changed username field selector to name=username')
  usernameFieldWasFound = true; }

  if (await page.$('#username') !== null) {
    USERNAME_SELECTOR = '#username';
    console.log ('Changed username field selector to #username')
    usernameFieldWasFound = true; }

  if (await page.$('#email') !== null) {
    USERNAME_SELECTOR = '#email';
    console.log ('Changed username field selector to #email')
    usernameFieldWasFound = true; }

    if (await page.$('[placeholder="Enter your username"]') !== null) {
      USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[placeholder="Enter your username"]' 
    console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[placeholder="Enter your username"]"')
    usernameFieldWasFound = true; } 
    
    if (await page.$('[placeholder="Username"]') !== null) {
      USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[placeholder="Username"]' 
    console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[placeholder="Username"]"')
    usernameFieldWasFound = true; } 
    
    if (await page.$('[placeholder="Email"]') !== null) {
        USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[placeholder="Email"]' 
      console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[placeholder="Email"]"')
      usernameFieldWasFound = true; }   

    if (await page.$('[placeholder="Please enter your username"]') !== null) {
      USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[placeholder="Please enter your username"]'
    console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[placeholder="Please enter your username"]"')
    usernameFieldWasFound = true; }  

    if (await page.$('[placeholder="Please enter your email"]') !== null) {
      USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[placeholder="Please enter your email"]'
    console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[placeholder="Please enter your email"]"')
    usernameFieldWasFound = true; }  

    if (await page.$('[placeholder="Please enter your email address"]') !== null) {
      USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[placeholder="Please enter your email address"]'
    console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[placeholder="Please enter your email address"]"')
    usernameFieldWasFound = true; }  

    if (await page.$('[type="email"]') !== null) {
      USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[type="email"]' 
    console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[type=email]"')
    usernameFieldWasFound = true; } 

    if (await page.$('[data-val-required="Please enter your email"]') !== null) {
        USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[data-val-required="Please enter your email"]' 
      console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[data-val-required="Please enter your email"]')
      usernameFieldWasFound = true; } 



    // failsafe incase username field is found but is not a real username field and there is a button
    // which is more likely to lead to a real login form
      if (await page.$('[class="mail-selector"]') !== null) {
      usernameFieldWasFound = false; }   




    // If no username field was found on the page this will trigger. 
    // The script should then click on any buttons with names that could lead to a login form and check again
    // This part of the script searches for buttons
  if (usernameFieldWasFound == false) {
    console.log('No username field was found, exploring buttons...')

    if (await page.$([type="submit"]) !== null) {
      CTA_SELECTOR = [type="submit"];
      console.log ('Changed button selector type=submit')
      console.log ('Button was found')
      buttonWasFound = true;
    }
  
     if (await page.$('[type="submit"]') !== null) {
      CTA_SELECTOR = '[type="submit"]' 
    console.log ('Changed button selector to "type=submit"')
    console.log ('Button was found')
    buttonWasFound = true;}
  
  
    if (await page.$('#loginbutton') !== null) {
      CTA_SELECTOR = '#loginbutton' 
      console.log ('Changed button selector to #loginbutton')
      console.log ('Button was found')
      buttonWasFound = true;}
  
  
    if (await page.$('#submit-btn') !== null) {
      CTA_SELECTOR = '#submit-btn' 
      console.log ('Changed button selector to #submit-btn')
      console.log ('Button was found')
      buttonWasFound = true;}

    if (await page.$('[class="mail-selector"]') !== null) {
      CTA_SELECTOR = '[class="mail-selector"]';
      console.log ('Changed button selector to class=mail-selector')
      console.log ('Button was found')
      buttonWasFound = true;}

      if (await page.$('[data-ga-slug="login"]') !== null) {
        CTA_SELECTOR = '[data-ga-slug="login"]';
        console.log ('Changed button selector to [data-ga-slug="login"]')
        console.log ('Button was found')
        buttonWasFound = true;}
  }  
    // if a username field was found sets boolean to true
  if (usernameFieldWasFound == true) {
    buttonWasFound = true;
  }
    // if no plausible button was found the script has failed and will/should end here. 
  if (buttonWasFound == false) {
    console.log('No login form could be found on this URL or the most plausible button leading to a login form on this URL.');
    await browser.close();
  }

  // username field was not found however a plausible button was found which may lead to a username field
  // Therefore button will be clicked and username field should be searched for on next page
  if (usernameFieldWasFound == false && buttonWasFound == true) {
    console.log('Username field was not found on first page but a pluasible button was found')
    console.log('Clicking button...')
    await page.waitForSelector(CTA_SELECTOR);
  await page.click(CTA_SELECTOR);
 
  // giving page time to load possible new login form
  await delay(1000);

    // searches for a username field on new page
    if (await page.$('[type="text"]') !== null) {
        USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[type="text"]' 
      console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[type=text]"')
      usernameFieldWasFound = true; }  
    
      if (await page.$('#si_username') !== null) {
        USERNAME_SELECTOR = '#si_username';
        console.log ('Changed username field selector to #si_username')
        usernameFieldWasFound = true; }
     
      if (await page.$('[name="username"]') !== null) {
        USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[name="username"]' 
      console.log ('Changed username field selector to name=username')
      usernameFieldWasFound = true; }
    
      if (await page.$('#username') !== null) {
        USERNAME_SELECTOR = '#username';
        console.log ('Changed username field selector to #username')
        usernameFieldWasFound = true; }
    
      if (await page.$('#email') !== null) {
        USERNAME_SELECTOR = '#email';
        console.log ('Changed username field selector to #email')
        usernameFieldWasFound = true; }
    
        if (await page.$('[placeholder="Enter your username"]') !== null) {
          USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[placeholder="Enter your username"]' 
        console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[placeholder="Enter your username"]"')
        usernameFieldWasFound = true; } 
        
        if (await page.$('[placeholder="Username"]') !== null) {
          USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[placeholder="Username"]' 
        console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[placeholder="Username"]"')
        usernameFieldWasFound = true; } 
        
        if (await page.$('[placeholder="Email"]') !== null) {
            USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[placeholder="Email"]' 
          console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[placeholder="Email"]"')
          usernameFieldWasFound = true; }   
    
        if (await page.$('[placeholder="Please enter your username"]') !== null) {
          USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[placeholder="Please enter your username"]'
        console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[placeholder="Please enter your username"]"')
        usernameFieldWasFound = true; }  
    
        if (await page.$('[placeholder="Please enter your email"]') !== null) {
          USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[placeholder="Please enter your email"]'
        console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[placeholder="Please enter your email"]"')
        usernameFieldWasFound = true; }  
    
        if (await page.$('[placeholder="Please enter your email address"]') !== null) {
          USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[placeholder="Please enter your email address"]'
        console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[placeholder="Please enter your email address"]"')
        usernameFieldWasFound = true; }  
    
        if (await page.$('[type="email"]') !== null) {
          USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[type="email"]' 
        console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[type=email]"')
        usernameFieldWasFound = true; } 
    
        if (await page.$('[data-val-required="Please enter your email"]') !== null) {
            USERNAME_SELECTOR = '[data-val-required="Please enter your email"]' 
          console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[data-val-required="Please enter your email"]')
          usernameFieldWasFound = true; } 

    // now username selector is either changed to correct one, or not found. If it's changed to correct we can continue with script
    // if it's not found we give up

    if (usernameFieldWasFound == false) {
      console.log('No username field was found after clicking plausible button. Script over');
      await browser.close();
    }

  
  
    }

 

  await page.waitForSelector(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
  console.log('Clicking username selector');
  await page.click(USERNAME_SELECTOR);
  console.log('Inputting fake username');
  await page.keyboard.type(C.username, {delay: 100});




// If clicking a next button after inputting username is required this will trigger here. 
  if (await page.$('#next') !== null) {
    CTA_SELECTOR = '#next';
    console.log ('Changed button selector to #next')
    console.log('Clicking button.')
    await page.click(CTA_SELECTOR);}







  if (await page.$('#si_password') !== null) {
    PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '#si_password';
    console.log ('Changed password field selector to #si_password')
    passwordFieldWasFound = true;}

  if (await page.$('#password') !== null) {
    PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '#password';
    console.log ('Changed password field selector to #password')
    passwordFieldWasFound = true;}

  if (await page.$('#pass') !== null) {
    PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '#pass';
    console.log ('Changed password field selector to #pass')
    passwordFieldWasFound = true;}

  if (await page.$('[type="password"]') !== null) {
    PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '[type="password"]' 
  console.log ('Changed password field selector to type=password .')
  passwordFieldWasFound = true;}

  if (await page.$('[placeholder="Enter your password"]') !== null) {
    PASSWORD_SELECTOR = '[placeholder="Enter your password"]' 
  console.log ('Changed password field selector to [placeholder="Enter your password"] .')
  passwordFieldWasFound = true;}

  // In the unlikely event that no password field can be found the script will end here.
if (passwordFieldWasFound == false) {
    console.log("A password field could not be found. Script has failed to send fake credentials.")
    await delay(3500);
    await browser.close();
}

  console.log('Clicking password selector.')
  await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
  console.log('Inputting fake password');
  await page.keyboard.type(C.password, {delay: 100});

  await delay(1000);



// phone number

if (await page.$('[name="phn"]') !== null) {
  PHONE_SELECTOR = '[name="phn"]' 
console.log ('Changed username field selector to [name="phn"] .')
phoneFieldWasFound = true; }

if (await page.$('[name="phone"]') !== null) {
  PHONE_SELECTOR = '[name="phone"]' 
console.log ('Changed username field selector to [name="phone"] .')
phoneFieldWasFound = true; }

if (await page.$('[name="phonenumber"]') !== null) {
  PHONE_SELECTOR = '[name="phonenumber"]' 
console.log ('Changed username field selector to [name="phonenumber"]')
phoneFieldWasFound = true; }

if (await page.$('[name="number"]') !== null) {
  PHONE_SELECTOR = '[name="number"]' 
console.log ('Changed username field selector to [name="number"]')
phoneFieldWasFound = true; }

if (await page.$('[placeholder="Enter your phone number"]') !== null) {
  PHONE_SELECTOR = '[placeholder="Enter your phone number"]' 
console.log ('Changed username field selector to "[placeholder="Enter your phone number"]"')
phoneFieldWasFound = true; }

if (await page.$('[placeholder="Please enter your phone number"]') !== null) {
  PHONE_SELECTOR = '[placeholder="Please Enter your phone number"]' 
console.log ('Changed username field selector to [placeholder="Please Enter your phone number"]')
phoneFieldWasFound = true; }



if (phoneFieldWasFound == true) {

  console.log('Clicking phone selector.')  
  await page.click(PHONE_SELECTOR);
  console.log('Inputting fake phone number') 
  await page.keyboard.type(C.phone, {delay: 100});

}



if (await page.$('[type="button"]') !== null) {
  CTA_SELECTOR = '[type="button"]' 
console.log ('Changed button selector to type=button ')}


if (await page.$('[name="Login"]') !== null) {
    CTA_SELECTOR = '[name="Login"]'
  console.log ('Changed button selector to "[name="Login"]"')}


  if (await page.$('#loginbutton') !== null) {
    CTA_SELECTOR = '#loginbutton' 
    console.log ('Changed button selector to #loginbutton')}


  if (await page.$('#submit-btn') !== null) {
    CTA_SELECTOR = '#submit-btn' 
    console.log ('Changed button selector to #submit-btn')}

    if (await page.$([type="submit"]) !== null) {
      CTA_SELECTOR = [type="submit"];
      console.log ('Changed button selector type=submit')}

     if (await page.$('[type="submit"]') !== null) {
      CTA_SELECTOR = '[type="submit"]' 
    console.log ('Changed button selector to type=submit ')}

    if (await page.$('[href="javascript:login();"]') !== null) {
        CTA_SELECTOR = '[href="javascript:login();"]' 
      console.log ('Changed button selector to "[href="javascript:login();"]" ')}

    if (await page.$('[id="login-submit-button"]') !== null) {
        CTA_SELECTOR = '[id="login-submit-button"]'
      console.log ('Changed button selector to "[id="login-submit-button"]" ')}

    


 


   
  console.log('Clicking submit button') 
  await page.click(CTA_SELECTOR);
  console.log('Sucessfully sent fake credentials.')
  delay(3500);
  // 2nd click as some submit buttons will fail to send credentials with one click, this may be because some phishing kits
  // will arbitrarily tell the user that their credentials are invaid after clicking once and only accept creds on 2nd click



  if (await page.$(CTA_SELECTOR) !== null) {
  page.click(CTA_SELECTOR); 
  console.log ('Reclicked button selector')}

  //  await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});

  browser.close();



function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
      setTimeout(resolve, time)
  });
}}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is declaring and immediately running all the functions `iterations` times, and they're running in parallel.

Instead try do declare everything once and only run the main function how many times needed:

```
(async () => {
  for (i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    await playTest(URLL);
  }
  process.exit(1);
})();
```

Also please note that in `process.exit(1)` 1 means "error", and by this you basically mean "the script failed".